# How to count the columns from tables in Databricks in SQL

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql

Please, how can I count the number of columns from tables in a SQL notebook in `Databricks`? The `information_schema.columns` is not working.

I was trying to run the query below:

```
select 'data_beat' Table_Name
         ,max(_createTime_) as Last_Create_Date
         ,max(_upt_) as Last_Update_Date 
         ,**(select count(*)
            from information_schema.columns
           where Table_name = 'data_beat'
          ) as Column_count**
          ,(select count(*)
                from data_lineage.field_dependencies
                where source like 'ett.data_beat%'
        ) as Count_to_L1
     from ett.data_beat
```

Expected Results are:

```
| Table_Name   | Last_Update_Date | Last_Create_Date | Columns_Count | Count_to_L1 |
| --------     | --------         |
|ett.data_beat | 5/10/2023        | 5/10/2023        | 51            |12           |
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Table or view not found: information_schema.columns; line 5 pos 17;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried in my environment and got same error.

[image]

As per this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-information-schema), and as far as I understood, **`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` requires unity catalogue to be created and it will give the details for those tables under that unity catalogue**. This might be reason for it to not identifying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

So, make sure your tables are under a unity catalogue to use    `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

And another workaround can be using some Pyspark code in between the SQL cells to store the column details in a temporary view and using it to get the count.

**My Sample:**

```
%python
df=spark.sql('show  columns  from sample1')
df.createOrReplaceTempView("columns_sample1")
```

```
%sql
select count(*) as count from columns_sample1;
```

[image]